# Do you do make multiple attack rolls when you hit multiple creatures with the same attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack-roll, improvised-weaponry

I was DMing a quest where the player was in a library getting attacked by 8 gnolls. He was at low health and outnumbered so he ran, but first knocked over a bookcase on 3 of the gnolls.

**In the future, should I make an attack roll to hit each creature or one for all creatures, since it's one book case?**

Comment: You don't seem to be describing anyone actually making an attack. Could you clarify exactly what is happening here?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the way I read it, OP had the bookcase make an attack roll against the gnolls.

Comment: What did you rule in the moment? How did it work out? Having tried it one way are you inclined to try the other?

Answer (score 9):

A more standard approach might have been to get each gnoll to make a dexterity saving throw, which represents them having to take some action to avoid being crushed by the bookcase.

In this case, you would roll each gnoll's saving throw separately, as they all have their own agency.

Comment: What do you mean by "more standard"? Is this approach "standardized" some where such that it can be called "standard"?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It’s a common way to say ‘common’. They don’t mean literal standardisation.

Comment: This is probably the correct way to handle this, however this answer could be improved by quoting rules on attacks or environmental hazards.

Comment: @Andrendire I concur; For refrence Ben, they can be found respectively in the *Basic Rules* or *Player's Handbook* in chapter 9, and the *Dungeon Master's Guide* in chapter 5